# WKInterfaceImage and dynamic images on watchOS 2

Tags: apple-watch, wkinterfaceimage

If I create a UIImage and display it using a WKInterfaceImage it always displays the image as @1x instead of @2x resulting in a pixelated image.  It worked fine with watchOS 1.  How to fix this behavior with watchOS 2?  The same code works fine on iOS with a UIImageView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for creating the image from an `NSData` object on the Apple Watch at the correct screen scale.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData scale:[[WKInterfaceDevice currentDevice] screenScale]];
```